# Azure Storage browsing client software options

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-queues

As far as I know, these are the only clients available to browse Azure Table Storage, Queues and Blobs:

- [Visual Studio Server Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ff683677.aspx):  This is great, but we need standalone software (for testers, analysts, etc.)
- [Cerebrata Azure Explorer](http://www.cerebrata.com/labs/azure-explorer): $125 per license. We cannot afford this as of yet.
- [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer): $50 per license. We cannot afford this as of yet.
- [TableXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer): Free but very limited (also no queue or blob storage)
- [Azure Storage Explorer 4](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/):  Many people suggest this but I find it to be very poorly written.
- [Azure Storage Explorer 5](http://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/):  Still in preview.

Are there any other clients out there that I am unaware of?

Comment: I would make a few corrections to your list above:

 - Cerebrata Azure Explorer is currently free. They have other paid products (like Cloud Storage Studio and Azure Management Studio). But you will only get blob support with Azure Explorer.
 - Other product you may want to look at is zudio (http://zud.io). It's not free but has a subscription based pricing so that may be affordable. 
 - CloudXplorer V1 is free, its for V2 you have to pay. Combine that with TableXplorer, you get 2 free products. You would still need to worry about Queues support.

Comment: Although Azure Storage Explorer isn't perfect, I have been using almost daily for the last 1.5 years.  It handles most things you would need to do without issue.  If you can get past its basic nature, its still one of the better ones out there.  Cloudberry Explorer for Azure Blob Storage is another great tool but just for Blobs.

Comment: I have been using Azure Storage Explorer 5 for a while.  I wouldn't let the 'preview' aspect stop you from using it.

Comment: So I've tried out Azure Storage Explorer 5.  Everything works great except that I can't refresh queue messages without having to close and reconnect to the storage account.  It's terribly frustrating.

Comment: Below is a list per Azure Storage Blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2010/04/17/windows-azure-storage-explorers.aspx

Comment: I wrote a fast and easy Storage Table Browser: https://github.com/amithegde/AzureTableBrowser

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 has and Extension available called CloudExplorer for Visual Studio 2015. I've been using it since beta in combination with Azure Storage Explorer. The benefit of the extension is the ability to search because I find the storage explorer loads large datasets very slowly, often crashing.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/84e83a7c-9606-4f9f-83dd-0f6182f13add

Answer (score 0):

There is a native Windows 10 client as well - https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/p/storamp/9nkv1d43nll3